# Schedule Tasks Ubuntu - No such file or directory

Tags: batch-file, ubuntu, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule a task to make back up every day. I'm using Ubuntu 15.10. For back up I'm using freefilesync with Scheduled Tasks. In freefilesync it's generated one batch file to execute the task. When I execute this batch strait from the command line it works OK. When I execute it from Schedule Tasks I get this error:

```
/home/fernando/BatchRun.ffs_batch: line 1: ?xml: No such file or directory
/home/fernando/BatchRun.ffs_batch: line 2: FreeFileSync: No such file or directory
/home/fernando/BatchRun.ffs_batch: line 3: MainConfig: No such file or directory
/home/fernando/BatchRun.ffs_batch: line 4: Comparison: No such file or directory
/home/fernando/BatchRun.ffs_batch: line 5: Variant: No such file or directory
/home/fernando/BatchRun.ffs_batch: line 6: Symlinks: No such file or directory
/home/fernando/BatchRun.ffs_batch: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `1'
/home/fernando/BatchRun.ffs_batch: line 7: `            <IgnoreTimeShift>1</Igno'eTimeShift>
Press ENTER to continue and close this window.
```

I read something about chroot environment but I can't get the solution.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to execute a config file.

Comment: The **batch-file** tag is for Windows based computers. If you are using Linux then you would use the **bash** tag or whatever shell script you are using.